# Rails MySQL query using where statement

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

I have this users:

**NAME** **_____** **ROLE**_________**STATUS**

user1 -------- role1 ---------------- true

user2 -------- role2 ---------------- true

user3 -------- role2 ---------------- false

user4 -------- role3 ---------------- false

user5 -------- role4 ---------------- true

I have this query:

```
User.where("role = ? OR role = ? OR role = ? AND status = ?", "role1", "role2", "role3", true)
```

and i expect that the data will be retrieve is:

user1

user2

but the system retrieve the user3 even if his status is false.

I also try to change `AND` to `OR` but it retrieves all.

what's wrong about my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with the query is the lack of parentheses around the 'OR groups'

```
User.where("(role = ? OR role = ? OR role = ?) AND status = ?", "role1", "role2", "role3", true)
```

However, as already stated in another answer, it can be done in an easier way like this.

```
User.where(status: true).where(role: %w{role1 role2 role3})
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
User.where(status: true).where(role: ["role1", "role2", "role3"])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using parentheses to group the conditions:

```
User.where("(role = ? OR role = ? OR role = ?) AND status = ?", "role1", "role2", "role3", true)
```

The tricky bit might be the `true`, is it just stored as a string? e.g. a `varchar` or `text` column?

As an alternative, you can also use the `IN` operator

```
User.where("role IN (?, ?, ?) AND status = ?", "role1", "role2", "role3", true)
```

Comment: User.where("role IN (?, ?, ?) AND status = ?", "role1", "role2", "role3", true) ---> works in me! Thanks for the answer :)